# Sum count column in raster attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-2.7

I am a beginner to python coding in GIS. I want to calculate the total number of counts in raster attribute table. In order to do that:

1. I would like to build a attribute table of raster data
2. use a loop through attribute table using ARCPY.SearchCursor()

Therefore, I wrote a code to build an attribute table. However, I am getting an error while running the code and not able to figure out the error in the code.

Code:

```
import arcpy
# Create the geoprocessing object 
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
gp.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/raster-read"

#Build Raster Attribute Table
gp.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("sti-9", "Overwrite")

Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Subhasis/Test/raster-read/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    gp.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("sti-9", "Overwrite")
ExecuteError: ERROR 000049: Failed to build attribute table
Failed to execute (BuildRasterAttributeTable).
```

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: First of all avoid special characters like - or & or spaces in folder and file name. Secondly you can only build attribute tables for rasters that are INTEGER. So if you have a FLOAT raster this tool will fail

Comment: Thank you very much1! I want ask yo stupid question. In order to check whether my raster is an INTEGER OR FLOAT, i looked at the layer properties and found that pixel type is unsigned integer. Is this the right way to check whether the raster is integer or float?

Comment: An unsigned integer is an INTEGER raster, so that sounds OK. I would suggest removing those special characters from your folder and file name.

Comment: I checked the special character and ran the code and got the below message :Build Raster Attribute Table example failed.
Executing: BuildRasterAttributeTable sti9 NONE. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be mixing different geoprocessors, you do not need to use the arcgiscripting.  Try this code, replacing the folder and file names as appropriate

```
import arcpy

#Set environment settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Temp"

#Build Raster Attribute Table
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("myRaster", "Overwrite")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for bothering you! I ran your code and got the message below:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Subhasis/Test/raster-read/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("sti9", "Overwrite")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13214, in BuildRasterAttributeTable
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000049: Failed to build attribute table
Failed to execute (BuildRasterAttributeTable).

Comment: Hmmm... At this point the only idea I have left is to ask if it's file locked by another application or running process? As the code above works for me.

Comment: Hi Just a quick question, I have the attribute table for raster and using the arcpy.searchcursor to read the attribute table. When I ran the program, I didn't get any error message. But I didn't see the "count" for each row in my "Python shell" window. Any thoughts..Providing code in the next comment:

Comment: import arcpy

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/raster-read"

#Build Raster Attribute Table
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("sti-9", "Overwrite")
    
# loop through attribute table
Rows = arcpy.SearchCursor( "sti-9" ) 

for row in Rows:
    count = row.getValue( "COUNT" ) 
    print count